# error de lectura de datos de lector de codigo de barras usb con nodejs y serial port

Tags: javascript, nodejs, serialport, código-de-barras

Estoy creando una pequena app que recoja los datos del lector de codigo de barra externo y genere un archivo de texto con cada scan que se haga y que todo esto funcione en background.

actualmente uso windows 11, un escaner de mano conectado a la computadora por usb marca sick modelo idm140-300S. tengo instalado node.js 18.12.1 npm 8.19.2 serialport 10.5.0 readline 1.30 socket.io 4.6.1

tengo el siguiente codigo en un archivo server2.js:

`````
````const { SerialPort } = require('serialport');
const { ReadlineParser  } = require('@serialport/parser-readline');
const fs = require('fs');

const port = new SerialPort({ path:'COM1',baudRate: 9600 });

const parser = port.pipe(new ReadlineParser({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));
parser.on('data',console.log)
port.on('open',function(){
  console.log('esta abierto')
})
console.log('estoy listo')````
`````

cuando ejecuto el comando: node server2.js recibo este error:

node .\server2.js
estoy listo
esta abierto

Lo que deseo es que cada vez que escanee un codigo automaticamente se genere un fichero con el valor del codigo de barras y la fecha en que fue escaneada, luego yo usare ese fichero para algo. Mas adelante en vez de un fichero lo hare a una base de datos, pero lo primero es capturar los datos de los escaner desde background

Answer (score 0):

En este caso esta conectado por USB tu lector de codigo de barras por lo cual no es un serial port como lo mencionas. Para que esto funcione tu equipo lo deberia de detectar como serial port, verifica en el Device Manager de Windows y te diriges a la seccion de PORTS/Puertos y veras que no aparecera, pero si te vas a la seccion de Keyboards/Teclados te mostrara que esta ese dispositivo por lo cual debes buscar otra manera de realizar lo que quieres.

Comment: cuando accedo a la sesion keyboards no me lo lista. Descargue de la pagina oficial los drivers y los instale. Tambien el software propio de la marca llamado SEEit y me dice que el scaner esta en el puerto COM1